# excel_sheets function in R gives : Error: Evaluation error: zip file - when reading an excel file which is open in MS EXCEL

Tags: r

Why does `<b>excel_sheets</b>` function in `<b>R::readxl</b>` package - not read from excel files which are open?

I tried searching for anwer on google and in stackoverflow threads but could not find any answers. Closest i get was to understand that this package detects the file as a zip file if the excel file is open. But i couldn't find why.

````
library(readxl)
boy.file.names <- list.files("boys",full.names = TRUE)
## all files are saved in a folder called boys in my working directory ##

excel_sheets(boy.file.names[[1]])```
## if i have this excel file open in MS EXCEL application i get this error ##
----------------------------
Error: Evaluation error: zip file 'boys/~$1996boys_tcm77-254026.xlsx' cannot be opened.
-----------------------------
````

I expected the file read operation not to be affected by open/close status of the file. But the R package can read the excel file as soon as i close it on MS EXCEL.

Comment: Could you provide an example of an excel file with this problem? Without an excel file, it is difficult to replicate your error.